# aspxFileUpload.FileBytes is obsolete?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, devexpress

I'm using `aspxFileUpload` to upload file. Doing something like this

```
bytes[] fileBytes = aspxFileUpload.FileBytes;
```

and then I just save it in database. Everything is working fine, just I'm getting a warning `aspxFileUpload.FileBytes` and `aspxFileUpload.FileName` is obsolete.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<dx:ASPxUploadControl ID="uploadControl" runat="server" Width="280px" 
        ClientInstanceName="uploadControl" 
        onfilesuploadcomplete="ASPxUploadControl1_FilesUploadComplete">
</dx:ASPxUploadControl>
```

Use the `client-side event` named `TextChanged`.

```
if(uploadControl.GetText() != '')
    uploadControl.UploadFile();
```

Then use the `server-side event` named `FileUploadComplete` and get that file in some global variable or session and use it where ever you want.

```
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FilesUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FilesUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (uploadControl.UploadedFiles != null && uploadControl.UploadedFiles.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < uploadControl.UploadedFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            Session["Photo"] = uploadControl.UploadedFiles[i].FileBytes;
        }
    }
}
```